# The same UI as in Contacts (buttons and a table view in the same place)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Please go to your Contacts app, and choose one of your contacts.

You'll see that the view has labels, buttons and a table view all in the same view. And you can also scroll it around.

I want to set up the same kind of UI.

How would I organize things in interface builder to accomplish this? I would imagine I’d have to create a regular UIViewController subclass, and create a XIB file with a scroll view, which in turn contains the buttons and table view? I tried, but it doesn't give me the desired effect. For example, the view refuses to “bounce” upon scrolling.

Comment: Similar look but different data :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a UITableViewController and create the Table you want.

The buttons are costum Table cells in the UITableView with round rect buttons in it. They have selectors to call methods.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Wrong answer, poster wants something different, but I'll let the answer stand because people might land here while searching.

What you probably want is the [ABPeoplePickerNavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Apple has [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/QuickContacts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009475) that demonstrates how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be using tableview or might be just a UIVIew with ScrollView and labels+buttons. You approach is right and it'll bounce if your view size is larger than your screen size

Comment: I’m trying to lay this out on IB. Sadly, the view is automatically resized to the screen size, even if the view is bigger. I unchecked "autoresize subviews" for both the scroll view and the view inside it. (The scroll view is, by the way, the top-level “view” of the view controller.)